# differentiate two html elements with same class

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath

I have this html code below and I want to differentiate between these two `PagePostsSectionPagelet` as I only want to find web elements from the **first** `PagePostsSectionPagelet`. Is there any way I can do it **without using** `<div id="PagePostsSectionPagelet-183102686112-0"` as the value will not always be the same?

```
<div id="PagePostsSectionPagelet-183102686112-0" data-referrer="PagePostsSectionPagelet-183102686112-0">
   <div class="_1k4h _5ay5">
       <div class="_5sem">
       </div>
   </div>
<div id="PagePostsSectionPagelet-183102686112-1" class="" data-referrer="PagePostsSectionPagelet-183102686112-1" style="">
   <div class="_1k4h _5ay5">
       <div class="_5dro _5drq">
           <div class="clearfix">
               <span class="_5em9 lfloat _ohe _50f4 _50f7">Earlier in 2015</span>
               <div id="u_jsonp_3_4e" class="_6a uiPopover rfloat _ohf">
               </div>
           </div>
       <div id="u_jsonp_3_4j" class="_5sem">
           <div id="u_jsonp_3_4g" class="_5t6j">
               <div class="_1k4h _5ay5">
                   <div class="_5sem">
                   </div>
               </div>
```

Tried using `//div[@class='_1k4h _5ay5']//div[@class ='_5sem']` but it will return both.

Using `//div[@class='_5dro _5drq']//span[contains(@class,'_5em9 lfloat _ohe _50f4 _50f7') and contains(text(), '')]` will help me find the second `PagePostsSectionPagelet` instead.

Comment: You can use the following selector `div#PagePostsSectionPagelet-183102686112-0 div[@class='_5sem']`

Comment: but what if the numbers _183102686112_ in `PagePostsSectionPagelet-183102686112-0` is not a consistent one? for instance, it might be another value the next time. @nikhil

Comment: @newbie_22466 - Well then you need to explain the question a little more as from what you have written does not give complete information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use the following xpath:

```
//div[contains(@class,'_1k4h') and contains(@class,'_5ay5')]
```

as selenium doesn't work properly with search of several classes in one attribute.
I mean By.Class("_1k4h _5ay5") will found nothing in any case and By.Xpath("//div[@class='_1k4h _5ay5']") can also found nothing in case of class will be "_5ay5 _1k4h" or " _5ay5 _1k4h".(as they possibly generated automatically, its may be have different position on page reload)

But for the best result by performance and by correctness I think will be the following xpath:

```
".//div[contains(@id, 'PagePostsSectionPagelet')][1]" -- for first div
".//div[contains(@id, 'PagePostsSectionPagelet')][2]" -- for second div
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that dynamic in the div id is only the number so you can use something like:

```
WebElement element = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[contains(.,'PagePostsSectionPagelet')])")[1];
```

This will take only the first web element.

Comment: its returns as an invalid xpath despite changing your code to `WebElement element = dr.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(.,'PagePostsSectionPagelet')])")[1]);`

Comment: WebElement element = dr.findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(.,'PagePostsSectionPagelet')]")[1];

Comment: im not sure if you have noticed, but there's missing bracket somewhere and theres this **array required, but By found** error

Answer (score 0):

Try using a css selector as below and refine further if required.
The code below returns a List of matching WebElements and then you grab the first one in the List.

```
List<WebElement> listOfElements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div[data-referrer]"));

WebElement myElement = listOfElements.get(0);
```

Hint: use the Chrome console to test your css and xpath selectors directly. e.g. use 
$$("div[data-referrer]") in the console to reveal what will get selected.